# Why am I getting strange indexing error in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I created a C# Web Application in Visual Studio 2010.  Then I copied some ASPX files (and the code behind) from another VS solution.  I had to go through and clean up some references and stuff.  Eventually I got everything cleaned up except one strange thing.  In VS I am seeing the red squiggly lines on the following line of code:

```
if (Request.QueryString["b"] != null)
```

The lines are beneath the Request.QueryString["b"] portion.  When I hover over it I see the following error message:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'

This is in the Page_Load event for the code behind on a page.  The really strange thing is that if I build the project it builds fine without any problems and the red squiggly lines go away.  But then if I close and re-open the file - I see the same red squiggly lines and VS is complaining again.

Any ideas?  I am baffled.  I tried rebuilding, cleaning the solution, closing VS and re-opening, etc.

EDIT: Here is the using part of the file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
```

Also, here is the header from the ASPX file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="beamswitch.aspx.cs" Inherits="AIMSWeb.data.beamswitch" %>
```

Comment: Do you have installed any plugins, like ReSharper?

Comment: No.  The strange thing is that this exact same code worked without any problems in the other solution.  Also, it is showing the red squiggly lines under all references to the Request object (Request.Form, Request.ServerVariables).  Very strange.

Comment: if you F12 on QueryString, where do you reach ? Do you have a using System.Collections.Specialized ?

Comment: try `if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["b"]))`

Comment: Corey, what does the using section at the top of the .cs file look like also have you tired changing the project to upgrade it to .net 4.0 project then downgrade it again to 3.5 recompile it..?

Comment: you can also check `if(Request.QueryString["b"] <> string.Empty){ }`

Comment: can you show what the Header of the .aspx file looks like also show what the Pag_Load method looks like.. I think I know what's going on, especially if you upgraded the file from an older version of .Net 1.1 for example.

Comment: It's not so much that the way I am checking the query string is wrong.  EVERY reference to Request.QueryString[somevalue] has red squiggly lines beneath it.

Comment: can you please show the .aspx page header .. also what version of .net was this file copied over from...? start simple them move to the more complex.. you said you copied and pasted some code.. well perhaps the code pasted maybe correct but what about how the .aspx file was created.. did you copy paste that or did you let the IDE generate it for you..?

Comment: Also, I didn't upgrade the project at all.  The other project was .NET 4 and this project is .NET 4.  I simply copied over some code files.

Comment: Also, if I create a brand new ASPX page in this project I have the same problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23232/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-corey-burnett)

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found out why this was happening.  The ASP.NET application that I am building is going to be a client to a WCF Service that I already built.  Part of the process of creating the client is using the Microsoft utility to generate an app.config file and a proxy.cs file.  Those files are then used in my ASP.NET application to provide proxy code that I can use so that I can call the service from my ASP.NET files.  When I removed those files from my solution the problem went away.

Specifically I am guessing that the problem had to do with the fact that one of the methods in my service was trying to serialize and send the Request.Form object as a parameter.  I am wondering if the code in my proxy.cs file was causing conflicts or something.  I am going to try rebuilding my service to maybe use a dictionary or something instead and then see if that fixes the issue.  Very strange.  Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I rebuilt my service to use a Dictionary object instead of trying to pass Request.Form as a parameter.  Then I used the svcutil.exe to recreate my proxy.cs file.  Then I added the proxy.cs file to my project.  Now everything is back to normal.  Whew!