# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'

Tags: c#, .net, collections, configuration

I've tried everything under the sun to get access to the AppSettings and I cannot get this to work.

I've got a class library that needs access to the web AppSettings. I've checked and there is no
**'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'** to import.

Anyone got any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public static class httpresponsebase_setoauthfromcookie
{
    public static void SetOauthFromCookie(this HttpResponseBase response, string verify,
                                          string token, string tokenSecret,
                                          string userName,
                                          bool isTwitter)
    {


        string pas =  WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cryptpass"],
               crypt = ((verify.Length > 3 ? (verify + ":") : "twit") + token + ":" + tokenSecret).Encrypt(pas);
        //
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(userName + (isTwitter ? "twitter" : "linkedin"), HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(Convert.FromBase64String(crypt)));
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }}
```

[image]

Comment: Verify that your project is not compiling against the Client Profile Framework.

Comment: Also post real code and not a Screen shot of your code makes it very hard to read all relevant pieces

Comment: The library is being complied against the 4.5 framework and not the Client Profile.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482250/why-am-i-getting-strange-indexing-error-in-vs-2010

Comment: That's not even close hatchet. I'm working in a class library and the 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection' is not available to import.

Comment: It's similar in that visual studio may be giving you a bogus error. I have nearly identical code as yours for accessing AppSettings, and have never seen this error, ever. I was throwing out a possibility. That's why it was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I actually find it easier to read the screenshot although, admittedly, you must right-click and select "Open image in new tab"

Answer (score 3):

I added a reference to System 4.0 and that fixed everything .

Comment: I have only System 2.0. How can i fix that??