# 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings' is not supported by the language

Tags: c#, web-applications, config

I am trying to access a value from my app.config but keep getting the following errors:

```
'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings' is not supported by the language

Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'
```

At the top of my file I have

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

and the following line doesn't work

```
string k = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
 </startup>
 <appSettings>
   <add key="key" value="test" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you add a reference to the System.Configuration.dll?

Comment: I tried to reproduce it without success.

I added reference to System.Congifuration and the row worked for me.
I received "test" in the 'k' parameter.

Comment: @rene Yes, the reference is added

Comment: Check version of System library. It should be 4 or higher... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194148/cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-system-collections-speci